# android listview with real-time sensor updates

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listactivity, listadapter

I am working on a app that shows some places in a listview. In every listview item there is a arrow pointing towards the place(hotel, bar etc).

The problem is I don't know how to keep this arrow updated efficiently, without cashing views locally( which, according to a Google I/O video, is something i should never ever do).

The arrow needs to be updated on every phone orientation sensor event, which is many times a second.

So is there a better approach than calling notifyDataSetChanged() on every event and refiling every list item data?

**UPDATE** (for @dharan and anyone interested):

I have stopped working on this project because I have a full-time job now, but I thought of a solution (unimplemented/untested).

First limit the angle of rotation to a fixed step, (eg: 5, 10, 15, 20, ... 355, 360) then cache the rotated image for each angle of rotation in order to avoid expensive image rotation calculations (but at a higher memory cost).

After that I would make my getView() method know when to only update the image instead of all the data. In my case this is as easy as:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if (convertView != null && place[position].id == (Integer)convertView.getTag()){
         //the place information is already set correctly so just update the image
     }
     ...
}
```

After these modifications I believe that calling notifyDataSetChanged() should not cause serious performance issues.

Comment: To update a `View` from a row in a `ListView` you have to use the `notifyDataSetChanged()` so you don't have any alternatives. The part about `ListView` + calling `notifyDataSetChanged` *many times a second* doesn't sound to good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have too many items in the ListView you could convert to using a plain LinearLayout and control those items individually.  The problem with LinearLayout though is if an item changes its size then everything (ie all children) has to be relayed out.  So triggering a change in one item can re-trigger other things to layout as well.  Now because you're changing a compass needle you might be able to skirt around it because that shouldn't cause each row to change its overall size.  You just need to repaint that item.

The other option is to write your own layout that takes some short cuts making some assumptions the general purpose layout managers can't.  The last thing I might look at is what does notifyDataSetChanged() does under the covers.  You might be able to extend ListView and write a method that only redraws the row that changed (of course this assumes the height of the row hasn't changed).  If the row height changes then everything after that row has to be relayed out.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestions, I will have a lot of items so I don't think I should use LinearLayout. I've done some reading and came across the idea of using BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter, can i have your input on that? The part I am not looking forward to is implementing the ListAdapter and Adapter interfaces. also +1

Comment: oh and the height of the row will never change because i just need to rotate a image inside a ImageView with fixed dimensions, everything else stays the same.

Comment: Right.  If you continue to use ListView you'll want to create a subclass of BaseAdapter.  It's not terribly hard to subclass.  The harder part would be implementing a fast update process you need.  If you can get access to the instance for the row you want to update then call invalidate() on it that should redraw it without performing layout again.

Comment: On second thought you might just try using good old fashion notifyDataSetChanged().  I'm currently working on building a music app and I have places in my app where in a list I'm displaying music downloading or playing using notifyDataSetChanged() to update the UI and it performs well.  Now I'm not updating more often than say 1 sec, but that gives you pretty good feedback while giving the CPU a rest.  I'd try this before going down the harder path of redrawing each element individually.

Comment: Maybe you are right, premature optimization is the root of all evil, I'll tag a view with the position in the adapter it's currentlly displying, i'll know when the rest of the views are showing the right info and only redraw my arrow

Comment: @bughi can u please post a solution for this,I am also trying to do the same thing but I am facing issues with sensor rotation.Thanks

Comment: @bughi Thanks for your reply.Initially I am loading list view with calculating bearing between current and destination and rotating image basing on bearing angle after that I need to update list view based on the orientation of device.Can u tell me what did u do to adjust bearing according to orientation.Thanks